# Не создается таблица Django orm

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Пытаюсь создать таблица `blocks_color` используя миграции, миграция создается после makemigrations но когда использую `migrate` не хочет создавать таблицу. У меня уже есть таблица `blocks_blocks`, не создается `blocks_color`.

Файл models.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Blocks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя блока')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    blocks_color = models.ForeignKey('Color', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name='цвет блока')


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Блок"
        verbose_name_plural = "Блоки"
        ordering = ['name']

class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Цвет', db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Цвет'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Цвета'
        ordering = ['color']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color
```

Вот что пишет после написания миграции

`python3 manage.py makemigrations blocks`

```
  blocks/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Color
    - Create model Blocks
```

`python3 manage.py migrate`

```
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, bboard, blocks, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: У вас были старые миграции и вы их удалили, да?

Comment: да, были проблемы с id класса Colors, поэтому удалял саму таблицу и миграции.

Comment: Ну вот и зря, теперь пересоздавайте базу заново или удаляйте неактуальные записи об удалённых миграциях из таблицы django_migrations

Comment: А по другому проблема никак не решается?

Comment: После того, как вы разломали механизм миграций, лёгких путей уже не будет